# How to write insert comment for complex array<struct<...>> type in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.test_complex_alter(
    `id` STRING,
    `items` array<struct<
        quantity: INT,
        articleData:struct<subsysNumber:string>,
        pickedReason:string>> 
) STORED AS ORC;
```

How to `INSERT` data into this complex table using `INSERT` Query?

Comment: where would the data for `insert` come from?

Comment: You could define a JSON table of the same schema, add data to it, then insert/select from it

Comment: Is there , any way to insert `ORC` table, my testing was after inserting into table, i would like to alter the `items.articleDate` field with adding one more field and understand the behavior .

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer to the OP:

1. Create a dummy table with 1 row ( schema doesn't matter). Let's call it `dummy`.
2. Run the below query to insert 1 row into your `test.test_complex_alter` table:

`INSERT INTO TABLE test.test_complex_alter SELECT "id1", array(named_struct('quantity',20, 'articleData', named_struct('subsysNumber', 'subsys1'), 'pickedReason', 'reason1'),named_struct('quantity',30, 'articleData', named_struct('subsysNumber', 'subsys2'), 'pickedReason', 'reason2')) from dummy;`

#### Structure of the array(2nd col):

`array(named_struct(n1,v1,..,nn,vn),...,named_struct(n1,v1,..,nn,vn))`

#### Results:

```
hive> select * from test100.test_complex_alter;
OK
test_complex_alter.id   test_complex_alter.items
id1 [{"quantity":20,"articleData":{"subsysNumber":"subsys1"},"pickedReason":"reason1"},{"quantity":30,"articleData":{"subsysNumber":"subsys2"},"pickedReason":"reason2"}]
```

#### Ref:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF -> "Complex Type Constructors"